# In app email will send email but won't dismiss in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have read other threads and tried multiple variables.

I have an app that attaches a screenshot to an in-app email.
When I press the send or cancel button the email doesn't dismiss.

Not sure if I have a delegate for this action.

Code:

`.h`

```
- (IBAction)openMail: (id)sender;
```

`.m`

```
//Open Mail
- (IBAction)openMail: (id)sender {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);

NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage,2.0);

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] ) {
    MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]           
init];
    mailComposer.delegate = self;
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png"   
fileName:@"attachment.jpng"];

    /* Configure other settings */
    [mailComposer setSubject:@""];
    [mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil]];
    [mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"%@", nil]];
    [mailComposer setSubject:@"4-4-2 Tactics/Line Up"];
    //[mailComposer setMessageBody:AddNotesTextField.text isHTML:NO];
    [mailComposer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];

    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller   
didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error{
if (error) { UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:  
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %@", [error description]] delegate:self 
cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

newMedia = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it figured out.

Here is what I needed.

//Open Mail

```
- (IBAction)openMail: (id)sender {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);

NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage,2.0);


MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailComposer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    [mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"%@", nil]];
    [mailComposer setSubject:@"4-4-2 Tactics/Line Up"];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:AddNotesTextField.text isHTML:NO];
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"attachment.jpng"];
    [mailComposer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
}

newMedia = YES;


}
```

Very subtle change

Comment: What's the change besides the order and the different way of setting the delegate? I'm having the same problem but can't get it fixed

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```